# adding a table as parameter in a query string in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlparameter

I have the following query :

```
   ALTER procedure [dbo].[jk_insertAllLocation]
   @locationTbl as locationTable readonly,
   @TableName varchar(100)
   as
   declare @tbl as locationTable,@sql varchar(max)
   begin
        set @sql = 'insert into ' + @TableName +'(location_id,name,address,latitude,longitude,distance,state,sub_cat,id_cat,icon_link,checkinsCount,IDSearch)
        select * from ' +  @locationTbl
        exec sp_executesql @sql
   end
```

I need to pass a table and a table name as parameter and I need to insert in the table name (`@TableName`) passed as parameter all the data in the table (`@locationTbl`) passed as parameter

but I know that I cannot concatenate the table (`@locationTbl`) in the query ...

so how can I fix this?

Comment: This is usually a sign of a broken data model - each of those tables must have an identical structure, which probably suggests that part of the *data* has been misused and has ended up in the table *names*. What you probably ought to have is a single table with this common structure and additional column(s) which contain the data that is currently being used to decide which table a row belongs to. I'd hope you wouldn't have `MaleEmployees` and `FemaleEmployees` tables...

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever True, but unhelpful if she doesn't have design control.

Comment: This is not efficient or pretty, so I won't submit it as an "answer"... but it would work:  first write out @locationTbl to a PERMANENT table, then put that `workTable` in your `select`.  Two approaches:  either (1) re-use the permanent table, with unique columns (like a primary key that changes for every row, and `initialPrimaryKey_andDateTime` that stays the same for all rows in **THIS EXECUTION** of the sproc), and then reference that unique column in your insert/select, or (2) build a unique permanent tablename for each execution, having the sproc `DROP` it, at start and end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [temp tables](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) (Temporary tables section on link):

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[jk_insertAllLocation]
  @locationTbl as locationTable readonly,
  @TableName varchar(100)
as
begin
  declare @tbl as locationTable,@sql varchar(max)
  if object_id('#_tmp_location_table') is not null drop table #_tmp_location_table
  select * into #_tmp_location_table from @locationTbl
  set @sql = 'insert into ' + @TableName + '(location_id,name,address,latitude,longitude,distance,state,sub_cat,id_cat,icon_link,checkinsCount,IDSearch) select * from #_tmp_location_table'
  exec sp_executesql @sql
end
```

Comment: i'm getting `the name is not a valid identifier?` on this line `set @sql = 'insert into ' + @TableName + '(location_id,name...`

Comment: it's okey i fixed it it was something from .net